# Has The core code of react native been refactored succefully?

Tags: react-native

I see the lastest version of `React Native` is `0.63` from the document. Based on my understanding, the Core code of the `React native` is been refactoring and will be finished by the end of this year. Currently we are trying to `re-develop` our app using `react native` and I have not heard any news of whether `React native` has been successfully refactored. Do I need to wait or just use `0.63`?

Comment: I would recommend to use 0.63. Latest version is the best choice, there is no need to wait.

Comment: yes as Vladimir says.
also it'll be easy to update react native in future if you wanted to do so as now you can see what files need to be replace/update for updated RN.